# How can I disassemble and install an old Schlage door knob?

Tags: doorknob

[image]I have an old brass Schlage unkeyed door knob/latch set. I would like to install it in a door, but can't figure out how to take it apart. The rosettes thread on, but I can't figure out how to get a knob off. There are 2 small holes on both knob shafts. I have already tried pushing something into the holes and pulling/turning the knobs.

Comment: 2 small holes in the shaft?  or one small hole in the shaft?

Comment: I added a bit more info for you.

Answer (score 2):

A pin in the small hole starts it. Pull on the handle as you push the pin in the hole. An ice pick or small nail will be strong enough to do what you need. After the knob is off, you may be able to remove the rosettes as you suggest, but a lot of the rosettes are removed by prying of the rosette by setting a flat screwdriver tip in the slot that is visible at the edge of the rosette where it meets the door. This is usually located on the low side of the rosette. After that is off, the 2 screws that hold the rest of the knob is visible.

[image]

This is for the other hole, this is just for the idea, the pin on this one is too big to fit in the hole of the rosette.

[image]

It takes a little finess to remove, first be certain you are able to depress the release. On practically every schlage I worked on, only one side will release. Once you know you have something depressed, lightly push and pull on the knob, you should be able to observe the slight movement of the knob at the hole were the pin is inserted, the hole will move one way then another to touch the pin. Once that is confirmed, pull the knob and release the pin after a firm pull is made. If it does not work on that side, try the other side. It will work.

Comment: I have already tried pushing something in the hole and pulling on the knob. This doesn't do anything.

Comment: You may not be applying enough force to release the spring retainer.

Comment: I added a bit more info for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the info, still nothin tho. A 2 mm allen wrench fits in the hole, and it's clearly the hole that's been used in the past is it's obviously enlarged as compared with the others (this is the hole near the bottom of the photo). I've also tried all manner of smaller things, picks and nails and pins.

Comment: Does the knob have any slop in it like I mentioned above around the hole where the Allen wrench goes in at? This is the way the knob comes off and they have froze in place somehow. Have you tried the exact same thing on the other side at the other hole that mimics the one you worked with already?

Comment: The Schlage 021415 spanner might be the correct special tool.  It has a knob-release poker and a pin spanner for rotating the coverplate.

Answer (score 1):

So I have the same lock, I bend a fork to use as the push pin, wiggle it with some force and got it to come off.

Comment: I really like the old fork idea.  You could also bend part of a cheap fork into a spanner-like hook to do the rotating of the face cover.  I'm going to remember that hack for use on other hook-spanner type nuts.

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn the inner handle until you see a small depression of metal. That is what you push into and pull the handle.

Comment: Welcome! I think your're on the right track - this is an important piece of information that was missing from Jack's answer. When there's an existing answer that does a pretty good job, especially if you don't feel like writing a comprehensive answer of your own, you could consider attaching your clarification as a comment to that existing answer.