# Tighten old 1960s doorknob

Tags: doorknob

I have a few doorknobs in an old 1960s house we just moved into that have a loose/wiggling collar (rose?). I can remove the knob on the inside by pushing in the silver tab on the side and pulling the knob out, but I can't figure out how to tighten or even remove the collar. I'm assuming it has something to do with the small circular hole in the collar, but I can't figure out what to do with that. I've tried a hex screwdriver and just pushing a pin into that (with and without turning or pulling on the knob at the same time), but no luck. Help!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: if there's nothing interesting in the hole, it might just be a spanner pin hole for something like https://absupply.net/schlage-021415-spanner-wrench-for-l-series-locks.aspx . If it is free enough, you might be able to fudge it by putting a pin, paperclip or allen wrench into the hole and twisting against it with fingers or a wrench or something.

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/133100/24213

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a type of spanner that amounts to a semicircle with a pin on the end.  The pin hooks into the hole, and the semi-circle wraps around the shaft.

You may be able to fake it with a small allen key to fit in the hole, and tapping on the key with a small hammer to drive it around one way or the other.[image]

This one looks to have too big a hook.  Try amazon looking for hook spanner wrench and/or pin spanner wrench.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I ended up ordering a Schlage M504-341 Spanner Wrench from Amazon, which worked perfectly to tighten the collar. Interestingly, the back of the collar had two slightly protruding screws that secure into the wooden door as the collar is tightened. I just needed to rotate the collar and re-tighten it to secure into a new location on the door.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy see the threads on the shaft ? You need to twist the  “hole cover” maybe after releasing a set screw at about 2 o’clock in the photo. Turning that cover clockwise will tighten it , 
if their is a set acres in that 2 o’clock position turn it the set screw or grub screw ccw and tighten the cover ,when  it is tight turn that set screw CW  to hold it tight. To me this hardware looks older and of higher quality than a 60’s house unless early 60’s , but this should help.

Comment: Look at those pics a bit closer. That shaft isn't threaded, it's just a trick of the reflection.

Comment: But those collars still have to turn as Ed indicated. this does look older than 60's...  We lived in a mid 50's and the collars just snapped into place.

Comment: A different scheme released the decorative "hole cover" by poking into an access hole like the one pictured. After doing so, you get access to the mechanicals of the latch, and there were two screws that clamp this side of the mechanism to the portion on the other side of the door.  If they are loose, the whole mechanism wobbles, and you can fix it by tightening them.

Comment: You might be right that these are older than 60's. The house itself was built in 1963, but I supposed these could have been vintage hardware pieces that the builder used. They do seem pretty high quality.

Comment: Funny the accepted answer is the same as mine except I did not provide a pic of a spanner as I was not sure if it had a set screw some do.